# Why does this code throw ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, iterator, set

Write a method removeEvenLength that takes a Set of strings as a parameter and that removes all of the strings of even length from the set.

My solution:

```
public static void removeEvenLength(Set<String> set) {
    for(String word : set) {
        if(word.length() % 2 == 0) {
            set.remove(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Input:
`[foo, buzz, bar, fork, bort, spoon, !, dude]`

Output:

```
ConcurrentModificationException on line 2:
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1115)
    at java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1169)
    at removeEvenLength (Line 2)
```

So I can solve it by creating an `Iterator`. But I want to know why the above code doesn't work?

EDIT:

Iterator doesn't work either:

```
public static void removeEvenLength(Set<String> set) {
    Iterator<String> i = set.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        String word = i.next();
        if(word.length() % 2 == 0) {
            set.remove(word);
        }
    }
}
```

Same error.

Comment: The "why": Collections in java.util are not thread-safe. Because of this, they added a check to test if the collection has changed when asking for the next item in an iterator. If so, it throws ConcurrentModification exception. Using Iterator.remove is safe because it's the same object doing the walking and removing.

Comment: Your method signature should probably be changed to `public static void removeEvenLength(Collection<String> strings)`, as this will allow you to use _any_ sort of collection (`Iterable<String> strings` is also an option).

Answer (score 5):

In this iteration `iterator` object is implicitly created. When you have `iterator` you can change collection just from iterator. In this case you are removing object directly, that's why this exception is thrown.

Create iterator, and remove object with iterator:

```
iterator.remove(); // removes current element
```

Comment: you are removing object directly again, see mu answer better.

Comment: `iterator.remove()` doesn't take any parameters, as it implicitly removes the 'last element returned'.  But yes, this is the problem.

Comment: You need to remove it using the iterator. Change your `set.remove()` call to be `i.remove()` and it should work. You cannot directly add or remove from a collection while iterating through it, but you can use the iterator itself to remove items.

Answer (score 2):

To understand why `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs, you will have understand the concept of [fail-fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) iteration. If a thread is iterating over a collection, and it realizes that the collection is being modified as the iteration is going on, the iterator will throw an exception rather than "probably" cause any integrity problems later on in the code.

Of course, not all iterators follow this approach, and using the Java `Iterator` will almost always ensure that the iteration never fails on modification.

To remove an element using the iterator, use this code

```
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        String obj = iter.next();
        if(<removal_condition_here>) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```